# Spring boot project add login endpoint to swagger API Doc (springdoc-openapi-ui)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, api-doc

I'm using java 17 and spring 2.6.3 and this package : springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.5
and I was wondering how I can add login endpoint to the swagger documentation ?
I'm using Spring's security package and login endpoint is provided for me but still I want it to be included in my Swagger UI.